# Why are 2.1A USB chargers 10W not 10.5W?

Tags: power-supply

This has baffled me ever since the iPad was released a few years back.  Why do power supplies designed for tablets output 2.1A but are marketed as 10W?  If anything, 10.5W rounds up to 11...  Or why don't they just use 2.0A supplies?

Comment: Marketing round scalar values to the nearest pretty text.  11W isn't pretty.  Is it a marketing of output power or a compliance with input power markings?  If the latter, amazing how they manage to get 100% efficiency.

Answer (score 6):

More than likely, at the full 2.1 amps load current, the output voltage will have dropped slightly below 5 volts to 4.76 volts - still an acceptable voltage for its use.

Note 4.76 volts x 2.1 amps = 9.996 watts

Come to think of it I believe the old standard for TTL power supplies is 5V +/5% = 4.75 volts to 5.25 volts. See [here](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_4/chpt_3/10.html) for confirmation. Also this picture: -

[image]

Taken from [here](http://infosys.co.kr/e002/e002-s01.html).

Comment: I wonder what would have happened if the 'charging' standard varied the amount of current devices were allowed to use based upon the amount by which the voltage exceeded 5.00 volts?  A device that wants to feed 1.5 amps into a battery could be free to do so as long as the supply voltage remained above 5.15 volts, but if the voltage dropped to 5.05 volts the device would have to cut back to half an amp.  A device fed by switcher that sags slightly when loaded near capacity would "automatically" draw the amount of current the supply was capable of providing at 5 volts.